# multiple folders for desktop background

Tags: desktop-background

I have a rotating background on one of my less used machines. With all the windows minimised it acts very well as a digital picture frame.

However my picture library is is in multiple folders. The wallpaper app seems to only use one folder. How can I get it to pull images from multiple locations or from sub folders in one location.

Would it be a good idea to create a new folder and fill it with symlinks to my actual pictures in their various locations? If I were to use the symlink method what command would I use to link all the files in a folder structure like ~/Pictures/date/picture.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

Here you're a pretty robust script to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER_WITH_ALL_PICTURES="/home/$USER/Wallpaper" # Output folder.
INPUT_FOLDER="/home/$USER/Pictures"              # Input folder.

mkdir "$FOLDER_WITH_ALL_PICTURES"

function link() {
    if [ -e "$2" ]; then
        link "$1" "$2_copy"
    else
        echo $1 $2
        ln -s "$1" "$2"
    fi
}

find "$INPUT_FOLDER" -type f | while read file; do
    link "$file" "${FOLDER_WITH_ALL_PICTURES}/$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Comment: Wow thank you that worked really well for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) is a tool which can do this (and much more) pretty easy with a GUI!
[image: Main preferences and menu]

since it is not in the default repositories you can install Variety via terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```